# Material UI theming: How to change the background color of a dropdown menu?

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

I have a problem with the theme below. Specifically, with regard to the background of the dropdown menu.  I am trying to get the dropdown background to 'white'.  It is currently displaying as the secondary theme color.  I've read the MUI theming docs with no success.

I suspect that I am not being specific enough in my selector for the MuiMenu paper backgroundColor?  I've stared at it for hours.  I've tried various adjustments to the MuiMenu rules.

Can someone please help me see/understand what I'm missing here?

```js
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#F96300',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#525254',
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiDrawer: {
      styleOverrides: {
        paper: {
          backgroundColor: '#525254',
          color: '#FFF',
        },
      },
    },
    MuiList: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: '#525254',
          '& .MuiListItem-root:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#F96300',
          },
        },
      },
    },
    MuiMenu: {
        styleOverrides: {
          paper: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
          },
          list: {
            '& .MuiMenuItem-root:hover': {
              backgroundColor: '#F96300',
              color: '#FFF',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your implementation, we did same in our app to change background color of `Menu` and it works fine.

```
components: {
  MuiMenu: {
    styleOverrides: {
      paper: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
      },
    },
  },
```

Please check the actual component wherever you're using it. It looks like you have added `bgcolor` or `backgroundColor` property in `sx` prop of the component which overrides your theme. Remove it and it will start picking up the color from your theme.